# Wordpress/Gravity Forms - How to show/hide items in a single <ul> list based on a checkbox being checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using Gravity Forms within a Wordpress installation and I'm attempting to create a parent/child-like structure within a single list of checkboxes. To clarify the structure I'm aiming for, note that there are 13 parent items, each of which has about 30 child items.

The goal is, whenever the checkbox next to one of the parent items is selected, the ~30 child items underneath that particular parent appear so they can be checked as well.

So, when the user first loads the page, the only items that would be immediately visible are the parent items.

**The difficulty here is that I can only work within a single unordered list, I cannot have multiple lists. Additionally, I cannot change the class of each list item, I have to work with the existing unique class assigned to each list item.**

I've been experimenting with some CSS/Java/JQuery solutions but I wanted to see what the community here thought would be the best way to approach this.

Here is an example of the HTML that makes up the list:

```html
<ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_4_67"><li class="gchoice_4_67_1">
                            <input name="input_67.1" type="checkbox" value="1160" id="choice_4_67_1" tabindex="3">
                            <label for="choice_4_67_1" id="label_4_67_1">3-D Printing</label>
                        </li><li class="gchoice_4_67_2">
                            <input name="input_67.2" type="checkbox" value="512" id="choice_4_67_2" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="choice_4_67_2" id="label_4_67_2">3-D Technology: Rapid Manufacturing/Prototyping Equipment</label>
                        </li><li class="gchoice_4_67_3">
                            <input name="input_67.3" type="checkbox" value="962" id="choice_4_67_3" tabindex="5">
                            <label for="choice_4_67_3" id="label_4_67_3">Additives: Accelerators</label>
                        </li><li class="gchoice_4_67_4">
                            <input name="input_67.4" type="checkbox" value="963" id="choice_4_67_4" tabindex="6">
                            <label for="choice_4_67_4" id="label_4_67_4">Additives: Antiblocking Agents</label>
                        </li><li class="gchoice_4_67_5">
                            <input name="input_67.5" type="checkbox" value="964" id="choice_4_67_5" tabindex="7">
                            <label for="choice_4_67_5" id="label_4_67_5">Additives: Antifogging agents</label>
                        </li>
          </ul>
```

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish would be, when the checkbox next to `gchoice_4_67_1` is selected, `gchoice_4_67_2, gchoice_4_67_3, gchoice_4_67_4, ...,  gchoice_4_67_20` would appear. When the checkbox is unselected, those list items would hide.

I've been playing around with this code, but it only works for one class. Is there a way I can get this to work for multiple classes? Maybe an array of some sort? Pardon my unfamiliarity with jQuery.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var checkbox = $('.gchoice_4_67_1');
    var dependent = $('.gchoice_4_67_2');
    if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
         dependent.show();
    } else {
            dependent.hide();
    }

    checkbox.change(function(e){
         dependent.toggle();
    });
});
```

**Thank you so much for any assistance you can provide, it's greatly, greatly appreciated!**

Comment: I've been playing around with this code, but it only works for one class. Is there a way I can get this to work for multiple classes? Maybe an array of some sort? Pardon my unfamiliarity with jQuery.

`jQuery(function ($) {
  var checkbox = $('.gchoice_4_67_1');
  var dependent = $('.gchoice_4_67_2');
  if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
    dependent.show();
  } else {
    dependent.hide();
  }

  checkbox.change(function(e){
    dependent.toggle();
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var trigger = $('#choice_4_67_1');
    trigger.change(function(){
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
            $('.gfield_checkbox input[id^="choice_4_67_"]').parent().show();
        } else {
            $('.gfield_checkbox input[id^="choice_4_67_"]').parent().hide();
        }
    })

});
```

^= basically says that it would match any id that starts with  "choice_4_67_". I think it should resolve your problem.

Comment: Many thanks for answering. The part of your code that makes it match any id that starts with "choice_4_67_" is fantastic. However, I noticed that your code checks the boxes that start with "choice_4_67_", the desired behavior is actually to show/hide the elements themselves (the list items).

Comment: I've just edited. Now it will hide every "li" element of selected inputs

Comment: Awesome, looks great, getting much closer, thanks a bunch for your assistance. The _only_ problem is, ideally, I am trying to hide a range of choices, which may not contain _all_ of the elements that start with "choice_4_67_"

For example, I may be trying to hide "choice_4_67_2" through "choice_4_67_20". Is there any way to select a **range** with this code? 

Again, thanks a bunch for your help with this!!!

Comment: Maybe you'll provide some jsfidle demo, cause I don't understand whole structure of what you're trying to do. Maybe I can advise a better solution in that case.

Comment: Thanks lomoboboo. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/ej429ybn/6/) a jsfiddle with the HTML of the list I'm working with.

I plugged in the code you provided.

The goal is, for example, that when "Additives" is checked, the **30 child items** under "Additives" will be shown. When it's unchecked, the child items would be hidden. 

This same behavior would repeat down the whole list with 13 total parent/child relationships (click on the parent, the child items appear). This would prevent the user from being bombarded by choices and make the list more manageable. 

Hopefully this is possible!

Comment: [Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgamwzbm/) I've removed a little bit `li` for convenience. Generally, you have to group your `li` elements into 3 or more separate `ul` and add script in the jsfiddle above. In the Gravity Forms you can do this for sure in the Admin panel>Gravity Forms>settings or whatever